# Is there a limit for loading sounds to soundpool loader in android?

Tags: android, soundpool

I have created an app that involves playing about 500 ogg files from raw (each files is about 20 to 30kb) the sounds are triggered when required. I am using sound pool. If I add sounds more than 475 ogg files to the raw folder. The app dies when loading sound to sound pool loader. Gives heap error. Is there any other service other media player or sound pool???

Does sound pool have limits for loading sounds?

Let me know !

Thanks!

Comment: I think the limit is in the amount of RAM you have available to you not necessarily just a hard cap on # of samples that can be loaded.

Comment: Can you please explain 'hard cap'?

Comment: Sure, I mean there is no "magic number" of samples that is too many. i.e. you are not having trouble because you've got >475 sampels. You are having trouble because the total size (in memory) of your samples is larger than the heap space you are being allotted. If lets say your samples were half as large, you could fit more of them before running into the issue I think.

Comment: Does that mean I can increase the heap size?

Answer (score 0):

For further people looking for this problem,

Try using [asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for loading the sounds.

An example on loading sounds with SoundPool:

```
private class LoadSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // something before starting to load sounds
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // actually loading sounds
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
            soundPoolId[i] = soundPool.load(context, soundResId, 1);
        }

        return "You are at PostExecute";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... a) {
        // update ui like loaded # sounds
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // something after loading all sounds
    }
}
```